# Count number of cells that match certain criteria with formulae

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets

Suppose I have column with dates:

```
2015-01-10
2015-08-12
2014-01-02
2015-01-28
2016-10-14
```

I want to count how many dates fall to January. I would supopse that formulae is like this `COUNTIF(A1:A20,"MONTH()=1")`, but it does not work. The answer for above set is `3`.

Comment: 3 looks like the correct answer to me. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @DavidPostill: The formulae I gave does not produce the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in Excel and Google Spreadsheets. I cannot confirm for OO-Calc.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(A1:A20)=1))
```

Where `A1:A20` is the list of dates.

This formula works by generating an array of `1`s and `0`s (`1` for dates with month equal to 1, `0` for all others) and adding the contents of the array. This is the same as counting those that match the month criterion.

Comment: I have found a side effect on Google Spreadsheets. `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(A1:A20)=12))` counts also empty cells.

Comment: [The forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/T0NpniWFOEs/96b1Z-_kDwAJ) provided a solution to the problem: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A20<>"")*(MONTH(A1:A20)=12))`.